# How to import an image in gazebo

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am using gazebo and I want to create a plane/ground with road lines. One way that I have been using and it is working is via importing the solid bodies found in gazebo, minimizing their dimensions and emulating the lines of a circuit. However this takes too much time. I want to ask if someone has a video or any other reference or he/she can tell me how to import an image as my ground (then all i have to do is draw the circuit in an image editor).

Kind regards,
Christos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26428/how-to-import-an-image-in-gazebo/) by [patrchri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40909/patrchri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the answer by checking in the forum:

https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4761/how-to-build-a-world-with-real-image-as-ground-plane/

---

Originally posted by [patrchri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/40909/patrchri/) with karma: 1 on 2021-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0